# TP4056 Output-Voltage too low when connected to Load

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated, lithium-polymer

I am designing a battery powered Esp32 board for the Institute I am working at. I recently got my hands on the board and the battery charging circuit has an issue. The TP4056 that I used should deliver 4.2V on its output when no battery is connected. However when I connect it to the HT7333 3.3V Linear regulator which supplies the ESP, I get around 3.6V delivered to the Input of the Linear Regulator and both STDBY and CHRG LEDs of the TP4056 light up. I tried it with those popular tp4056 modules as well they show the same problem. However everything works fine when I supply the regulator with 4.2V from an external LAB-Bench power supply. What could could cause this? I sadly am not allowed to share the entire Schematic of the board, due to it being technically Institute property. But here are the parts concerning the problem.

[image]

Any help or experience sharing would be much appriciated.

Comment: What is the voltage at the battery (BAT)? You have a diode between the two points, that could be dropping too much voltage.

Comment: The TP4056 is a battery charger.  It only puts out 4.2V when it thinks it is attached to a full battery (or open circuit).  It will put out less voltage depending on how much current it is sourcing...since it thinks it is trying to charge a battery.

Comment: evildemonic is right. I solved the issue, the battery voltage is not the issue, the esp wasn`t working properly, giving a brownout error. I thought the under voltage was the cause. But the problem was solved when I solved 2 100uF capacitors to the 5V input and 4.2V output. Which means it was a voltage stability issue. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The battery voltage was too low because the system was pulling too little current. Which in itself wasnt the issue. When I checked the 3.3V output of the linear regulator I realized it was outputting 3.2V -3.3V which is sufficient to operate the ESP. The issue was that when a battery isn`t connected there is a parasitic AC influence from the USB port. Which expains why it worked right from the Lab-bench power supply. The issue was solved when I added two, 100uF capacitors to the 5V input and "4.2V" output. I hope this helps other people who are going through a similar proccess.